# multi-ssh is giving error

Tags: ssh

I am trying to chain ssh as shown http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html

```
Host c0
   User myusername
   Hostname xx.xx.xx.xx
   ForwardX11 yes

Host c9
  ProxyCommand ssh -q c0 nc -q0 c9 22
```

This is not working with error:

```
ssh c9
bash: nc: command not found
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I can obviously do a

```
ssh -A -t c0 ssh -A -t c9 (where c9 is properly defined in c0 machine),
```

But, I am trying to get it all in my host machine's ssh/config

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing on c0 the tool nc .
nc is part of package netcat .

=> you must install netcat on c0

**Alternative**

if your local ssh support -W , you can try to replace :

```
 ProxyCommand ssh -q c0 nc -q0 c9 22
```

by

```
 ProxyCommand ssh -q c0 -W c9:22
```